# find index/value in excel table with multiple selections

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a tabular with a database like struktur:

[image]

I now want to seach for the row index of 
Objektiv = PA 10x0.3
Position = Fokus
Grenzfläche = Unten
Kamera = AVT

in order to get the value for contrast

I know how to search for a identifiable value using index and match. However I do not know how to apply this here for multiple values.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a simple or advanced filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[CONTRAST],Table1[CLM1],I2,Table1[CLM3],I3,Table1[CLM4],I4,Table1[CLM5],I5)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Contrast],MATCH(1,(Table1[Objektiv]="PA 10x0.3")*(Table1[Position]="Fokus")*(Table1[Grenzfläche]="Unten")*(Table1[Kamera]="AVT"),0))
```

Logic:

```
=INDEX(Result to return, MATCH(1, (Range for criteria1 = Criteria 1) * (Range for criteria2 = Criteria 2) * (Range for criteria3 = Criteria 3),0))
```

I did a table to make life a little bit easier and refer to the column names.

You could refer the criterias to individual cells too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a key column which concatenates the searched columns into 1 string. Then match against that string by concatenating your required values. I would also set the data up as an Excel table. This makes it easy to change you variable values.

[image]

Key column in A. Search values in column K

K6 uses Match to find the concatenation of the search terms above in column A keys. You can wrap in an IFERROR to handle match not found. The match is the row found it.

```
=MATCH(CONCATENATE(K2,K3,K4,K5),Table2[[#All],[Key]],0)
```